# Смена подписи в GIT в Intelij Idea, macOS

Tags: git, intellij-idea, gitlab, git-commit, gpg

Как сменить подпись своих commits?
Сейчас все commits подписываются моей учёткой с gmail.com

фото 1.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я сделал аккаунт на gitlab, генерировал и добавил gpg подпись. выбрал ее в настройке git

фото 2
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при коммите получаю ошибку

```
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

система macOS.
Если настройку с подписью выключить то подписывается подписью с gmail.com

Comment: что за учетка с гмэйла и как она попала в идею? чем должно подписываться на самом деле?

Comment: @Эникейщик аккаунт gmail использовался как почта для GitHub. Теперь проект на GitLab. В идее аккаунт GitHub я удалил, создал и подключил gpg ключ в профиле GitLab и как на фото 2 включил подпись. но почему то подписывается все равно gmail